# how to Create browser shortcut which will open certain pages?

Tags: firefox, email, browser, shortcuts

I don't like desktop email management softwares, such as outlook or zimbra, in the same time, i own more than 5 important email accounts,and want to keep updated when i receive any email on any of these accounts,

I am thinking to have a shortcut on my desktop which will open my browser with all my emails opened as they are the home pages.

But in the same time, don't want to make these emails pages the default home pages when i open the browser from its normal real icon.

Anyone have an idea how to do that?

I am using firefox, and my emails are on gmail, yahoo, live, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Right click your desktop and go to New -> Shortcut.
- In the program location, enter the location of Firefox (something like `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`)
- Once the shortcut is on your desktop, right click it and go to properties.
- In the "Target:" field, append links **with spaces between each** as shown here:

  [image]
- Apply & OK

May be slightly different for Vista & Windows 7.

Comment: its working the same way on windows 7, just created it on Windows 7 RTM and its working perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a shortcut to firefox.exe with all the sites you want to open as parameters:

```
 firefox.exe "www.site1.com" "www.site2.com"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the path to Firefox should be in quotes, as it may contain spaces. Also plain firefox.exe won't work unless it's binary location is in your path (I put mine in there long ago for little tricks like this) :)

Answer (score 1):

I use Chrome for that. There's a feature called ["Application shortcuts"](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710) which does just that:

> Do you rely heavily on some websites,
>   such as your email? If so, you may
>   want to create applications shortcuts
>   for these websites that can be placed
>   on your computer desktop, Quick Launch
>   menu, and Start menu for easy access.
>   ...
>
> When you double-click a shortcut icon,
>   the website opens in a special
>   streamlined window that doesn't
>   display tabs, buttons, the address
>   bar, or menus. Many of the browser
>   functions are available instead in the
>   drop-down menu that appears when you
>   click the page logo in the upper-right
>   corner of the window. If you click a
>   link that takes you to a different
>   website, the link opens in a standard
>   Google Chrome window so you won't lose
>   track of your website.