# How to open 10 tabs in FF and be automaticilly logged in (name:passwd)

Tags: firefox, shortcuts, auto-login

I have just read this article how to open more tabs via parameter in shortcut file already been asked here:
[how to Create browser shortcut which will open certain pages?](https://superuser.com/questions/51947/how-to-create-browser-shortcut-which-will-open-certain-pages)

But, I also need to be logged in, after this 10 tabs/10 addresses will be opened, I can save my credentials uname/passwd, but something needs to click on "Login" button to log me in.

Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/) to open and click the Login with the stored passwords.  There is also [iMacros](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/) for Firefox.