# Browser session shortcut for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, browser, shortcuts

In all the recent versions of Microsoft Windows, it is possible to make a shortcut for a web page, such that clicking on this shortcut opens that web page in a new tab.

It is natively possible to make a shortcut for a browser session/group of tabs, such that clicking on this shortcut "restores" this specific session on a new window?

If not, are there any workarounds?

I have to deal with a wide range of subjects and it becomes tedious to keep all the tabs open as it occupies a significant amount of RAM.

(Answers for Firefox, Chrome and Edge are encouraged.)

The method stated [here](https://superuser.com/questions/51947/how-to-create-browser-shortcut-which-will-open-certain-pages?rq=1) allows you to add only 3 tabs.

EDIT: By session I mean that on clicking the shortcut icon, a certain set of browser tabs are opened.

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question and expand on what you mean by "session". But FYI, a browser often has little or no control on how a server responds to requests for pages.

Answer (score 0):

Can use bookmarks or add shortcuts in google chrome as these will store the link address of the particular web page and you can always revisit them whenever you want.