# Firefox loses pinned tabs

Tags: firefox, tabs

I am using Firefox (on Windows), and have some pinned tabs. If I open a second browser window, it does not have those pins, but I can live with that.

What I don't like is that when I close the first windows (that has pinned tabs), and *then* close the second window (without pinned tabs), FF will not open my pinned tabs the next time.

Apparently this is by design, the reason being that you can have different pinned tabs in each window.

Is there a setting to change this behavior? Maybe by having the same pins in every window?

Comment: If you create a folder of bookmarks, you can just open all bookmarks in the folder by rightclicking it and clicking `Open all Bookmarks`...

Comment: Another option is to use the `Tab Session Manager` https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/tab-session-manager/

Comment: @Gantendo Ha, there's an add-on for everything! If possible at all, I'd like to do this without one

Comment: Or [My Sessions](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/my-sessions/)

Comment: I haven't tried it but this would probably work https://superuser.com/questions/51947/how-to-create-browser-shortcut-which-will-open-certain-pages

Comment: See my answer for a reliable built-in solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox design of Pinned tabs keeps them connected to one
specific window, where each window can have its own tabs.

To ensure not to lose pinned tabs, you either need to use
*File > Exit/Quit* to close Firefox or to close the window with
the preferred pinned tabs as the last window, as only that
window will be restored.

This has been the subject of numerous complaints for many years,
but hasn't changed in any way. One is then forced to use
extensions to work around the problem.

One extension that could help is
[PersistentPin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/persistentpin/) :

> This add-on makes sure that on opening the browser there are the same
> websites opened and pinned.
>
> The main use case for this if you want to clear your history when
> closing Firefox but still want to keep your pinned tabs.
>
> To configure the add-on go to the preference tab in the add-on menu
> (about:addons).
>
> This is a rewrite of the App Tab Initializer add-on. The rewrite was
> necessary since this add-on is compatible with the new multiprocess
> mode of firefox, which improves its speed greatly.
>
> If you have any problems or a suggestion feel free to open an issue on
> Github.

You may find the source of the extension on Github
[Faerbit / persistentpin-webextension](https://github.com/Faerbit/persistentpin-webextension),
where the developer is still answering issues.

Comment: The mentioned extension is currently not working. I also have the impression that it is no longer maintained. Therefore, I now stick to the more reliable Firefox history, as described in my answer.

Comment: @Wolf: It has good reviews from just a few weeks from today.

Comment: Well, it works, but you have to explicitly add your pinned tabs in the settings of the add-on. And (as I recently reported), the pinned tabs you currently have are closed by the installation of PersistentPin.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you close Firefox windows in the *wrong* order, there's a reliable built-in help.

You can find the closed tabs in: *History → Recently Closed Tabs*. If you select previously pinned tabs there (they should usually be at the top), they will also be restored as pinned tabs.

I didn't get on so well with *PersistPin*, the add-on that [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1825987/391675) reported on. But now I'm actually quite happy that I don't need another add-on.